# How do I get ClassTag from String to pass to a Scala Function as a type parameter?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I have a Scala function that is defined like

```
def func[V: ClassTag, VD <: kafka.serializer.Decoder[V]](implicit tag: ClassTag[VD]) = {}
```

I have the class name of `VD` that I am going to use while calling this function as a string e.g. `com.company.CustomDecoder`. How do I call the function above with the correct ClassTag?

Elaboration : 
I can call the function as

```
func[String, kafka.serializer.StringDecoder]
```

But how do I call this function given

```
val vClassStr = "java.lang.String"
val vDClassStr = "kafka.serializer.StringDecoder"
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to type the evidence parameter out, so I would write the above as:

```
def func[V, VD <: kafka.serializer.Decoder[V]](data: Int)(implicit tag: ClassTag[VD])
```

Then you can just use `tag` in your code. Otherwise you can do it using a type bound and using the helper `classTag[T]` to get it:

```
val tag = classTag[VD]
```

I think you have some syntax issues in your example.

EDIT: If you need to just construct the types from strings, just use `Class.forName` from Java.

```
func(v: String, vd: String, data: Int) = {
  val clz1 = Class.forName(v)
  val clz2 = Class.forName(vd)
  // etc
}
```

Comment: I corrected the syntax in my question. Also I didn't understand how I can use your solution to call my function given the name if the class. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you need to construct it from strings, you may as well just use `Class.forName("classname")`. The `ClassTag` type is to capture the information removed by erasure -- not to convert strings to `Class`.

Comment: I need to pass the class type to the function type parameters list. `func[Class.forName("java.lang.String"), Class.forName("kafka.serializer.StringDecoder")]` does not compile.

Comment: In my function I am actually trying to call [createStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html#createStream(org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,%20scala.collection.immutable.Map,%20scala.collection.immutable.Map,%20org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) in `KafkaUtils`. I need to pass `V` and `T` as `type` parameters and therefore cannot do `Class.forName`, which I would have preferred.